# Create project in Google API Console to enable OAuth2 to send emails in 2024

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

The Google Console user interface has changed and it is not very clear how to create a project to send emails from any account the user has. It would not be an exclusive project for the domain, but any user of the application could use the application through OAuth to send emails from their account.

I have tried to create a project indicating "No organization" in Organization but then it asks me for Location and does not allow me to enter anything there.

NOTE: The app does not work within Workspace, the project is simply created to register an app as described at [OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app)

Comment: Can I see a picture

Comment: I strongly discourage you from trying to use OAuth/Gmail/Workspace to send emails from a system. Create an account on an email service that supports this. There are dozens of reputable email senders. Some are Google Cloud partners with Google documentation such as SendGrid, Mailgun, and MailJet: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Finally I was able to create the project with a common GMail user account (not Workspace). But it would be interesting to understand how it should be created in Workspace. The app does not work within Workspace, the project is simply created to register an app as described at [OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app)

Comment: @JohnHanley The application does not run within Workspace, I only need to declare the project for a Mobile & Desktop App

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, I really appreciate your advice, but I'd like to learn and figure it out for myself.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I'm trying to modify a C# desktop application that sends emails, Google announced that App Passwords will stop working and I'm trying to modify the application to use OAuth 2.0. Do you think there is a tutorial to configure the project in Google Console?

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, I'll try to explain. My question is about Google Cloud Console, if you create a project with a common gmail.com user it will ask you for Project Name and Location, but if you create a project with a Workspace user (formerly G-Suite) it will ask you for Project Name, Domain and Location. If you in Domian select "No Organization" in Location you will have the problem. Could I explain myself well?

Comment: Apps password is used with SMTP server where are you seeing that apps password will stop working. You could still use xoauth2.   Or a service account with workspace

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to create a project, check your roles and permissions, as mentioned on official docs on [Creating a project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project) you must have the `resourcemanager.projects.create` permission

Comment: I'm an administrator, I guess I should have the permission.